# Syntaxnet pretrained models for Italian language

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, syntaxnet

I'm trying to use Syntaxnet pretrained models for Italian language. I just found one issue related to tokenization task on Italian and Spanish languages. I have got a preliminar problem. The posted link for pretrained dataset dowload does not work. Here it is : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md. Could someone provide me a working repository link? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/parsey_universal/Italian.zip

By the way, you can use this project for Docker as a basis for your own container. Just replace the model for Russian with the model for Italian.
https://github.com/IINemo/docker-syntaxnet_rus

This container implements standalone server that can be used in conjunction with syntaxnet wrapper:
https://github.com/IINemo/syntaxnet_wrapper

Comment: thanks. I just fixed the broken link in order to access to Italian Language Pretrained Models. thanks @ Chen Gupta

Comment: By the way, you can generate the SyntaxNet docker container for Italian with this [project](https://github.com/IINemo/docker-syntaxnet) now using the command from docker/main: `./build.sh <the cont name> it_IT.UTF-8 http://download.tensorflow.org/models/parsey_universal/Italian.zip`
  
Or just run:
`echo "La bellezza ha una verità tutta sua " | docker run --rm -i inemo/syntaxnet_ita`